# How to locally quantify the 'sharpness' of an image?

Tags: image-processing, python, blur

I am trying to quantify how much sharpness (or acutance) is in a picture which has some [bokeh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokeh) (out of focus background).

I am using the Python scikit image for that. Here is my naive approach:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import data
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.morphology import disk
from skimage.filters.rank import gradient

cat = data.chelsea() # cat is a 300-by-451 pixel RGB image
cat_gray = rgb2gray(cat)

selection_element = disk(5) # matrix of n pixels with a disk shape

cat_sharpness = gradient(cat_gray, selection_element)

plt.imshow(cat_sharpness, cmap="viridis")
plt.axis('off')
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

So here is the picture (notice the background not in focus)
[image: cat]

And here is the gradient, which actually measures the difference in contrast:
[image: Gradient]

This difference in contrast *problem* is more obvious if one uses the [Lena image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna):
[image]

Here, the background is caught as well due to the difference in contrast (there is a black frame on the top right)

Any ideas about how to give an scalar value where only the focused areas are highlighted?

Comment: What do you mean by "There is a black frame on top right"?

Comment: I've updated the description. The gradient highlights the edges that have contrast.

Comment: Your differentiating disc might simply be too large. In essence, a gradient is not much more than a high pass filter, and early autofocus units just did that: convolve the image with $(+1,-1,+1,-1)$ in its center and adjust the focus until they found a maximum.

Comment: Grateful for the concept of bokeh!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recent works I am aware of make use of tools that go beyond mere gradients. Here are a few references that could be starting points:

- [S3: A Spectral and Spatial Measure of Local Perceived Sharpness in Natural Images](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TIP.2011.2169974), 2012, with [examples of sharpness maps and Matlab code](http://vision.eng.shizuoka.ac.jp/s3/) (that could  be converted to Python)

> This paper presents an algorithm designed to measure the local perceived sharpness in an image. Our method utilizes both spectral and spatial properties
>   of the image: For each block, we measure the slope of the magnitude
>   spectrum and the total spatial variation. These measures are then
>   adjusted to account for visual perception, and then, the adjusted
>   measures are combined via a weighted geometric mean. The resulting
>   measure, i.e., S3 (spectral and spatial sharpness), yields a perceived
>   sharpness map in which greater values denote perceptually sharper
>   regions

- [Image sharpness assessment based on local phase coherence](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TIP.2013.2251643), 2013, with [examples  and (BROKEN yet) code](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~z70wang/research/lpcsi/) ([local copy of the code provided by the authors](http://www.laurent-duval.eu/Codes/TIP2013-code.rar))

> Sharpness is an important determinant in visual assessment of image
>   quality. The human visual system is able to effortlessly detect blur
>   and evaluate sharpness of visual images, but the underlying mechanism
>   is not fully understood. Existing blur/sharpness evaluation algorithms
>   are mostly based on edge width, local gradient, or energy reduction of
>   global/local high frequency content. Here we understand the subject
>   from a different perspective, where sharpness is identified as strong
>   local phase coherence (LPC) near distinctive image features evaluated
>   in the complex wavelet transform domain. Previous LPC computation is
>   restricted to be applied to complex coefficients spread in three
>   consecutive dyadic scales in the scale-space. Here we propose a
>   flexible framework that allows for LPC computation in arbitrary
>   fractional scales.

The given examples and comparisons across different  could provide you with  some hints toward your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent references. It's also nice that they provide MATLAB code, although for the second paper the link seems dead :/

Comment: @FZNB Sorry for that. Looking for an alternative. You can find more recent refs that cite these two. I tend to believe playing in the phase domain can be useful to that goal

Comment: I have a local version of the code for the 2nd paper. I'll make it available shortly

Comment: @FZNB I have told the authors about the broken link, they said they would fix it. Meanwhile, I have posted a local version

Comment: They did not fix it

Answer (score 2):

If you see the full Lenna image she will be standing so close to the mirror(black frame is a part of the mirror,so the **black frame is also in focus**), that's why you get that edge when calculating gradient. This is the reason why you are calculating gradient for black frame in this particular image.

If you need a general method, this is something I could think of:

> Finding the the maximum gradient of the image
>
> Get the approximate depth map(Hardest part to extract from single image)
>
> Filter the gradients that have more or less the same depth as the maximum gradient.